# Spring JdbcTemplate stuck on INSERT INTO...SELECT query

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, insert-select

Hi I am using Spring Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE. I have a situation where I need to fire

```
INSERT INTO someTable1 (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT (10346, someTable2Id, 1048) FROM someTable2.
```

I am using Spring **JdbcTemplate**.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO someTable1( col1, col2, col3 ) 
                   SELECT 10346, someTable2Id, 1048 
                     FROM someTable2";
             jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
```

While executing this statement, it got stuck on jdbcTemplate.update(sql) line.
It seems `JdbcTemplate` is not responding well to `INSERT INTO...SELECT` Statement.
Same query is working fine from Database Editors.

Comment: Is it possible that `someTable2` can have too much records ? Can you try the same for only 1 record from  `someTable2` by adding a `WHERE` statement. Can you provide the type of `jdbcTemplate` are you using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` ? And lastly are other calls from the BE to the DB working ?

Comment: @lazarov, I tried the same query with sql developer. It is working there. I tried both `JdbcTemplate` and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. It is giving me no error. But when I call `jdbcTemplate.update(sql)`, execution hangs there. Then I tried with normal `JDBC` program, still no error but execution hangs there. `someTable2` has nearly 700 records.

Comment: Did you get answer to this? If yes, can you please post here and help others? thanks :)

Comment: @AkshayLokur, I did not get any solution for this. I completely excluded `INSERT INTO...SELECT` from my application.

Comment: Use `jdbctemplate.execute()`

Comment: jdbctemplate.execute() is also stuck
anyone got fix for this?